# Sharing colormap between windows

Tags: x11, xlib

I create a x11 window using `XCreateWindow` function. I create colormap this way:

```
XSetWindowAttributes attribs = { 0 };
Colormap cmap = XCreateColormap(dpy, rootWindow, visualInfo->visual, AllocNone);
attribs.colormap = cmap;
```

`attribs` variable is passed to the `XCreateWindow`. In my application I want to create a few windows. Should I call `XCreateColormap` when creating a window or I can create colormap object once and share it between windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should create a colormap shared between windows.

Colormaps are resources (sometimes even hardware resources) and it doesn't make sense to waste them.

One doesn't create colormaps these days very often because true color displays are taken for granted, but back in the day with 256 or maybe even 16 indexed colours they were a thing. There was usually just one hardware colormap with 256/16 entries. Activating a window via a window manager would load that window's colormap into the hardware colormap. As a result, if a window had some non-standard colormap, inactive windows with different colormaps would display weird colours.

So if your application windows all need to display the same colours, they should just use one colormap. Otherwise on such an old indexed colour system they could show inconsistent colours. Example (in pseudocode):

```
colormap1 = XCreateColormap(...);
window1 = XCreateWindow (... using colormap1 ... );

colormap2 = XCreateColormap(...);
window2 = XCreateWindow (... using colormap2 ... );

XAllocColor (..., colormap1, pink); // allocates at index 13
XAllocColor (..., colormap1, beige); // allocates at index 14

XAllocColor (..., colormap2, pink); // allocates at index 14
XAllocColor (..., colormap2, beige); // allocates at index 13
```

Now when you select window 1, in window 2 pink and beige would swap places, and when you select window 2, the same happens in window 1. You would not be able to view both windows simultaneously in their intended colours.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have multiple windows with the same visual, you can use the same colormap for all of them because this allows you to save resources and avoid unnecessary colormap creation for each window, you just need to set the colormap attribute of each window to the same colormap object and as I see, you have already done that by setting the `attribs.colormap` to `cmap` before calling `XCreateWindow`.

so check this out :

```
Display* dpy;
Window rootWindow;
Visual* visual;
//for example if you have initialized dpy, rootWindow, and visual variables

Colormap cmap = XCreateColormap(dpy, rootWindow, visual, AllocNone);

XSetWindowAttributes attribs = { 0 };
attribs.colormap = cmap;

Window window1 = XCreateWindow(dpy, rootWindow, /* window1 attributes */);
Window window2 = XCreateWindow(dpy, rootWindow, /* window2 attributes */);
//make more windows as needed

//set the colormap attribute for each window
XChangeWindowAttributes(dpy, window1, CWColormap, &attribs);
XChangeWindowAttributes(dpy, window2, CWColormap, &attribs);
//set colormap attribute for other windows

//map and handle events for each window
// rest of your codes

//destroy the colormap when you no longer need it
XFreeColormap(dpy, cmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your application. If the color maps of all Windows are static or changed simultaneously, a single is preferred. But if you optimize the palette depending on the content, use independent maps.